# Is there an implementation somewhere of the yellow screen of death?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In ASP.NET when you are in `DEBUG` mode and something fails you get a the famous yellow screen of death.

It shows that there was a `Server Error in <Location> Application`, provides a description, exception details, source file and stack trace.

I would like to extend this error page to include some extra information.

- Is there an "open source" implementation of the yellow screen of death?
- Is there a way to extend the built-in yellow screen of death?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error page formatting is done by `System.Web.ErrorFormatter` and its subclasses, which unfortunately are internal. You can grab the HTML and modify it if you like using `HttpException.GetHtmlErrorMessage()`. But I'd be inclined to do as other commenters have suggested and use `Server.GetLastError` and format it myself.

If so - please ensure you `HtmlEncode` the error message output to mitigate XSS and ensure your production sites don't display any information about the error (as this was the attack vector for the [ASP.NET padding oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/2416728.mspx) decryption attack in 2010).

Comment: the trouble with the proposed solution with HttpException is that there seems to be no way to yank the HttpException, you can only intercept the SqlException ...

Comment: How about simply `new`-ing up an `HttpException` passing your `SqlException` as an `InnerException` and then calling `GetHtmlErrorMessage()`.

Comment: tried that ... did not get the formatter set ... only options seems to be DIY or an http module

Comment: Looks like (according to Reflector) if you newed up the subclass `HttpUnhandledException` using  `HttpUnhandledException(string message, Exception innerException)` it calls `SetFormatter`...

Comment: true ... see http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/09/08/Extending+the+ASP.NET+error+page+show+me+the+SQL+edition ... Im accepting this

Answer (score 4):

This page seems to have the info you're looking for.

http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs

Essentially, when an exception bubbles up to to the runtime it gets wrapped in an `System.Web.HttpException` (This was wrong.  At least I didn't see this behavior in MVC 3).

I'd think you can extend that class and override GetHtmlErrorMessage to return whatever extra data you want.

Update:  Well, with a little experimentation it appears I'd be wrong. BUT there is a workaround...

You can write the info from the exception in any manner you choose then clear the error and you'll have what you want returned.

Something like this...

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var error = context.Server.GetLastError();
    context.Response.Write(error.Message);
    context.Response.Write("<br /><br />");
    context.Response.Write(error.StackTrace);
    context.Response.Write("<br /><br />");
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    context.Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: In theory this works, however in mvc3 when it hits Application_Error you have a SqlException ... not an HttpException

Comment: re your edit, yeah ... I got that far ... its just that I don't have and HttpException so can not render the html for the yellow screen unless I hand code it

Comment: View Source and extract'll save you the trouble.  Then set up a nice razor template that'll render the exception and whatever extra data you want from it?

Comment: yeah ... I guess ... its a PITA ... thought there was an easier way

Comment: @Sam: Yeah, it seems MS thought better of extensibility at a bunch of places in the framework...

Comment: @Sam: It can even go in a nice IHttpModule implementation, so it's a drop in from web.config :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom error pages, I believe you can get the last error with `HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();` I'm not sure if there are any custom pages out there. But the content of the YSOD should be available from the context of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

See here:
http://www.oschina.net/code/explore/mono-2.8.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpException.cs

It's from the source code of mono (.NET for Linux), in versions < 2.10 (that is to say 2.8).
In version 2.10+, they started using templates, which makes it far more difficult to find and understand it.